# How do I better get current user id in Loopback

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

As the `loopback.getCurrentContext()` has long-living unstability problems and deprecated currently, how can I make sure that when a user performs some operations via API endpoints, I know how to identify him?

May be I can send the token id in the request payload and check it? What if user fakes it? What are alternatives to those hacky solutions from the issues page on Github?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Making+authenticated+requests

In summary, once you've logged a user in it should give you back an AccessToken in the response.
You can then use that in the headers or on the query string to prove you're a logged in user:

```
# Authorization Header
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
http://localhost:3000/api/widgets

# Query Parameter
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/widgets?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This cannot easily be faked, as the access token is checked on each request to ensure it's current and valid.

Once you've done this, you can get at the accessToken via (taken from https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/569#issuecomment-60924099 except attaching the user to the req object)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  app.currentUser = null;
  if (!req.accessToken) return next();
  req.accessToken.user(function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    req.currentUser = user;
    next();
  });
});
```

Add this to your `server.js` or a boot script and therefore have the `user` object on `ctx.req.currentUser` at any point.

Comment: Is it possible to get the ctx.req object in operation hooks?

Comment: No.  Not easily.  I've not managed to do it, and I've had a go.  Getting the user in Operation Hooks is currently the biggest Loopback problem I've come across.  There is an outstanding issue for it that is being looked it, but expect nothing in the short term.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What is the best approach for saving the current user in some owner property in the DB?

Comment: We do everything in the `beforeRemote` and `afterRemote` hooks.  For our 'updatedBy` type columns we have created mixins.  You do have access to the request object in these remote hooks, and typically the User is serialized onto these.